# Remove texts based on pattern

Tags: regex

I have a file with lots of URLs:

```
domain1.com/blue
domain1.com/blue/
domain2.com/red
domain2.com/red/
...
[etc]
```

**Is there a way for me to use Regex formula to keep ONLY the "domain1.com/blue" type of text, but DELETE "domain1.com/blue/"?**

The pattern is that all these URLs' end have the first part the same, but at the end some have a "/"; basically i want to remove all the URLs that have the "/" at the end but keep the ones without "/" at the end.

In the end the the file should only contain these:

```
domain1.com/blue
domain2.com/red
...
[etc]
```

Thank you so much for the help! If anyone has an idea how to do this, it'd be awesome!

Comment: Do you simply want to keep all lines not ending with a `/`, or do you only want to keep the only if they have a counterpart ending in a `/`?

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that you could do that I can think of.
1, Match all the lines in the file that do not satisfy your pattern and replace it with a single new line.
The regex for this `/^.*\/$/` and then replace with whatever.

2, Match only the lines you want to keep and save them to a new file.
The regex `/^((?!(\/$)).)*$/`

you can paste these into a regex [translator](https://regex101.com/) for in depth explanation as to what they're doing

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply, will test it and get back here

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you did not specify which language you are using with `regex`, so I can't give you language-specific details. But a line that ends with `/` followed by possibly one or more white space characters can be tested for with the following regular expression:

```
/\/\s*$/
```

So read in each line and test it against the above regex. It it matches, do not write it out to the *new* file.

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NZShao/1/)

Comment: I am just using a plain Notepad++ to do a find and replace search with regex expression across the file, hope that makes more sense

Comment: thanks a lot as well for the reply, will test it and get back here too